# HTML Javascript accessing id ordered

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the values from the javascript code using the ID. I want the value which is being held by the current ID. Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">

<title>This is my website</title>

</head>

<body>

<header align="center" id="head01"></header>

<p id="HouseName05"></p>

<footer id="foot01" align="center"></footer>

<script src="JavaS.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("foot01").innerHTML = "&copy;  " + new Date().getFullYear() + " Dane. All rights reserved.";
document.getElementById("head01").innerHTML = "Dane & Co";

document.getElementById("HouseName01").innerHTML = "House 1 name";
document.getElementById("HouseAddress01").innerHTML = "House 1 address";
document.getElementById("HouseImage01").setAttribute("src", "C:/Users/currys/Pictures/House01.jpg");

document.getElementById("HouseName02").innerHTML = "House 2 name";
document.getElementById("HouseAddress02").innerHTML = "House 2 address";

document.getElementById("HouseName03").innerHTML = "House 3 name";
document.getElementById("HouseAddress03").innerHTML = "House 3 address";

document.getElementById("HouseName04").innerHTML = "House 4 name";
document.getElementById("HouseAddress04").innerHTML = "House 4 address";

document.getElementById("HouseName05").innerHTML = "House 5 name";
document.getElementById("HouseAddress05").innerHTML = "House 5 address";

document.getElementById("HouseName06").innerHTML = "House 6 name";
document.getElementById("HouseAddress06").innerHTML = "House 6 address";
```

When i run the HTML code the header and footer display the correct value which is being held, where the id is equal to "head01" and "foot01". Although for some reason when i try and call the value with the id "HouseName05" nothing is displayed. In this page i don't want any other parts of the javascript id's just the header footer and the HouseName05.

Comment: Is this your actual code? Seems fine to me. Maybe you made a typo somewhere?

Comment: Check the console. As you don't have element with `HouseName01` ID, the code fails (attempt to access property `innerHTML` of `null`). It's not clear what you want to do here, but in general, before changing property of an element fetched from DOM (with `getElement.. or any other selector), make sure the result is there (not `null`).

Comment: He's got `head01` but none of the `House...` apart from `HouseName05`.

Comment: @Jack, any console error there?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null, i believe this is it

Comment: @Jack, That's what I assume. Check the Answer. Hope, It helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the console error, you need to check if the element is in the document before set the html at the element. You can create a function to do this.

```
var setInnerHtml = function(id, text)
{
   if(document.getElementById(id) !== null)
   {
       document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text;
   }
}
```

Then you can use the function like

```
setInnerHtml("head01", "Dane & Co");
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/r4w5vv1w/)

Comment: in the doom? Sounds fatal ;)